# xampp is not showing .php files saved in htdocs folder

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am using windows 7 and just installed xampp server to "E:\xampp" in my laptop to learn php. Now the problem is whenever I start xampp server by starting "xampp_start" in xampp folder and start Apache and MySQL from "xampp-control" and type localhost in my browser it automatically gets converted into "localhost/xampp/" and display a default page instead of displaying the .php file which I created in htdocs folder. 
 Another problem is when I created a folder in htdocs folder and saved a index.php and another .php file which was created by me, it is not showing that folder too. 
 I know this question has been asked before but I didn't get any solution from there because I started ***xampp_start from xampp folder and Apache & MySQL from xampp-control.*** So please help. Thanks in advance. 
This is the default picture which is being displayed: 
 [image]

Comment: So you created a folder within "htdocs" and then created an "index.php" inside that new folder? Then you tried "localhost/new_folder" and it didn't work? Also: When you run xampp_start did you look at the panel to see that Apache had actually started and was listening on ports 80 and 443?

Comment: @BigChris Exactly! Actually I created a folder named "work" in htdocs folder and saved a index.php file and another .php file named "myfirstfile.php" but as shown in the picture whenever I type localhost in browser it automatically gets converted into "localhost/xampp/" and if I try to change path like "localhost/xampp/work" it shows an error message like "Object not found". And yes I checked it from "xampp-control" Apache server started successfully. please help.

Comment: Try just "localhost/work". When you just put "localhost" you will always get the xampp splashscreen as you've experienced.

Comment: @BigChris Problem is still there. I tried "localhost/work" and as soon as I hit enter it automatically got converted in to "localhost/xampp/work/" and showed the same error "Object not found".
Two question from you, first is, the folder "work" which I made in htdocs folder contains a "index.php file". Now this "index.php" file should be empty or this is the same file which in htdocs folder and should "work" folder also contain "index.html" folder? And second question, Is it showing error message because I didn't install xampp in "C" drive, should I install xampp in "C" drive?

Comment: Inside your "work" folder create an "index.php" file and put in some random text. Open the browser and go to "localhost/work".

Comment: @BigChris Thanks a lot for your assistance. Problem is already solved. Look at the answer, I posted below :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is if you create any .php file in htdocs folder, you have to run that file as "localhost/filename.php" but if you created any folder in htdocs, for example folder name is "work" then you have to type "localhost/work/" and then it will show file contained in that folder.

Comment: I tried the above path but it shows "Object not found" even if I give the proper path

Answer (score 0):

First copy the files of htdocs and paste on any drive and delete the htdocs folder then create another folder and paste the files in this folder and  restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you go to Local Disk (C:), then go to xampp -> htdocs-> and create your folder.

Comment: Your answer does not contain enough information, nor is it accurate.
He has an htdocs folder, he just does not see the file.

Answer (score -2):

Hi Guys Here Iam  Gonna Show You How You Can Fix This Error
Follow me
        Don't worry ! If xampp is not showing .php files in htdoc/folder OK:
 Just change the name of that file which is not showing and refresh or reopen the localhost directory it will-be show 
Your file 
If this method work or not   comment below 
          Good luck and keep it up.
      @gamerinc

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please better explain in steps to help resolve this issue.